# What is equivalent of jQuery.ajax dataType raw in Spring RestTemplate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I have jquery ajax call as below

```
jQuery.ajax(url, {
        headers  : header_settings,
        type     : "POST",
        dataType : "raw",
        data     : JSON.stringify(data),
        success  : callback,
        error    : callback
      });
```

How we should specify dataType raw for Spring RestTemplate

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
.....
    restTemplate.postForObject(uri, request, String.class);
```

Comment: In jQuery, there is no `dataType` called `raw`. You can check [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax). Supported types are `(xml, json, script, or html)`. In fact you have set data as JSON string using `JSON.stringify(..)`!

Comment: Thanks Zico. Yep, understood.

Answer (score 0):

Intelligent Guess is the default and usually works for me. You can just delete the dataType line.